# Suppress section name and numbers on section pages of the Madrid theme

Tags: beamer, themes

Via `pandoc` you can generate Latex files based on Beamer. You can even choose a theme.

Pandoc automatically adds section pages at the start of sections. With the `Madrid` theme, they contain the section name and number (for example `Section 1` etc.) as the first line (marked with the red circle in the screenshot below).

How to remove this line?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot that shows where you want to remove the section title?

Comment: A wild guess: are you talking about the table of contents? If yes you should use `\section*{}` for a section that should not be shown in the toc instead of all these workarounds.

Comment: Sorry, no. I run Pandoc including a header file with some latex commands and receive a PDF-File. It is Pandoc which has access to all sections individually. I can only modify the header.

Comment: Can you clarify the question first? Show a screenshot of what you want to remove where?

Comment: About example: is it allowed to link to the Pandoc discussion group? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/_wgNIDupmZg, and the PDF-Output: https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=forums&srcid=MDQwMzcyMDI1OTg4NTI1Mzc0NzgBMTQ2NjI1OTkwODcwODk4NDk1MjkBbG9ReDduS0ZDZ0FKATAuMQEBdjI

Comment: Can you add an image to your question? (questions at tex.se should be self-sustained if possible to ensure that they will be helpful for future users with the same problem even if external links are no longer available)

Comment: How Pandoc creates slides via latex beamer: 1)\
$ echo '# Title' | pandoc -t beamer -o test.pdf -M theme=Madrid\ (I am afraid I am not entitled to upload the output, a PDF-File which shows "Section 1" and "Title". I want to get rid of "Section 1".)

Comment: Thanks for the image. This looks like a section page which is not used per default in beamer. Is it somehow possible to access the tex code in which pandoc converts your input file?

Comment: Do you want to remove the section pages for all sections or only for selected ones?

Comment: I do not want to delete "Section pages". I only want to remove the line "Section 1" including the number. About your comment: "not used per default in beamer" -- but Beamer draws a nice box around the title, which gives me the impression that Beamer is aware about sections (sections in beamer allow no other text on that page, it is only a structural heading slide).

Comment: Ah, I think I finally understand.

Comment: Can you somewhere add `\setbeamercolor{section name}{fg=white}` in your pandoc thingy?

Comment: With "not used per default in beamer" I wanted to say that those pages are not shown per default. One has to activate them in the presentation, something which maybe your pandoc converting thing does for you.

Comment: !!! (funny solution -- but it works!), thanks so much! About your other remark: I run my presentation as PDF, and PDF is probably not aware about beamer background.

Comment: I tried to clarify your question, please feel free to roll-back my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the section name and number the cleanest solution would be to redefine the section page template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\AtBeginSection{
   \frame{\sectionpage}
}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
  \begingroup
    \centering
%    {\usebeamerfont{section name}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section name}\sectionname~\insertsectionnumber}
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]{section title}
      \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{title}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{fr}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

A quick hack to hide the section name and number could be to simply change their number to the same colour as the background:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamercolor{section name}{fg=white}

\AtBeginSection{
   \frame{\sectionpage}
}


\begin{document}

\section{title}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{fr}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```